# C++ - set column names in HDF5

Tags: c++, hdf5

Is there a way, how to set column names in h5 file?

I can do this with compound datatype or it could be probably done using [H5Table](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5table.html).

One option is also to make attribute and save names of columns this way.

But usual matrices of single datatype can not have named columns, do they?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't set column name in an atomic datatype. As you have seen the trick of H5Table is that it creates a compund datatype where there is a field for each "column". [LINK](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/compound.html).

If I were you I would write the column names in an attribute (array of strings) and keep the datatype simple.

To create a list of strings in C++ I do as follows:

```
H5::H5File m_h5File;
m_h5File = H5File("MyH5File.h5", H5F_ACC_RDWR);
DataSet theDataSet = m_h5File.openDataSet("/channel001");
H5Object * myObject = &theDataSet;

//The data of the attribute.
vector<string> att_vector;
att_vector.push_back("ColName1");
att_vector.push_back("ColName2 more characters");
att_vector.push_back("ColName3");
const int RANK = 1;
hsize_t dims[RANK];
StrType str_type(PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE);
dims[0] = att_vector.size();  //The attribute will have 3 strings
DataSpace att_datspc(RANK, dims);
Attribute att(myObject->createAttribute("Column_Names" , str_type, att_datspc));

vector<const char *> cStrArray;
for(int index = 0; index < att_vector.size(); ++index)
{
  cStrArray.push_back(att_vector[index].c_str());
}
//att_vector must not change
att.write(str_type, (void*)&cStrArray[0]);
```